# Hiding scale x value in graph editor

Tags: after-effects, graphedit

Im trying to do a simple animation and the scales x value is constant and i dont need to edit at all. however it still show on the graph editor which would be fine if the handles on the keyframes didnt overlap. its not preventing me from getting the work done but its making it take a lot longer having to fiddle with finding just the right spot to grab the proper handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the "Separate Dimensions" button?

[Separate Dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTjUu.png)

If that doesn't work, you could try tying the property you want to edit (the y-value) to a slider value via an expression, and just editing in the expression.